# How can my bot recognize the 3rd word in a string and then repeat that word?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have made a bot for Discord using JavaScript, Node.js, and [discord.js](https://discord.js.org/). I would like to know how to pick up a word another bot says and repeat that word.

For example, the bot already in the channel will say this:

```
BOT: GC STARVING Mord [mord33] (0.2)
```

I need to find the third word in the message, and use it to send a message like this:

```
MYBOT: .aidfor Mord 10k gc
```

Answer (score 2):

Start with your message event. Check that the ID of the author is that of the bot you wish to repeat, so that other messages don't interfere. Then split the message into arguments, and send your message, implementing the third one. Make sure to also catch any rejected promise that may arise.

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.author.id === 'IDofBot') {
    const args = message.content.trim().split(/ +/g);

    return message.channel.send(`.aidfor ${args[2]} 10k gc`)
      .catch(console.error);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your message event, you can grab the third word sent by a bot like this,

```
client.on('message', (message) => {
    const thirdWord = message.content.trim().split(' ')[2];
    message.channel.send(".aidfor " + thirdWord + " 10k gc");
});
```

You get the message content by doing [`message.content`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content) (obviously), and then you can run the string operation [`trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) on that content. Trim removes the whitespace before and after the message so that there is no accidental spacing that ruins your third word catching.

[Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) can either take a regular expression (like [slothiful did](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56606500)), or you can pass in a character that will be the separator. It will return an array of the string but it will be separated by the separator (who knew, right?). And since arrays start at zero, we need to access the third string in the array, which is why we put a 2 in the brackets.